# Django Match ForeignKey from ModelChoiceField to MySQL

Tags: django

I have a *ModelChoiceField* called **outage_name**. I also have a simple form that allows you to select the item from the list. The ModelChoiceField is pulled from a MySQL DB. This queryset is located in forms.py

```
outage_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Outage.objects.filter(published = True)
```

The models.py is listed below.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Outage(models.Model):
    outage_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    published = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.outage_name

class Detail(models.Model):
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    outage = models.ForeignKey(Outage)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.outage
```

When I select from the list and submit the form I can't seem to figure out how to match **outage = models.ForeignKey(Outage)** that was selected on the list. To the correct **outage_name**. In my views.py I can hard code the id and it submits to the database and everything works fine.

```
def turnover_form(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = TurnoverForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():         
                details = Detail.objects.get_or_create(
                    detail  = form.cleaned_data['detail'],
                    user = request.user,
                    outage = Outage.objects.get(pk=1))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/turnover/user/')
        else:
            form = TurnoverForm()
        variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
        return render_to_response('turnover_form.html', variables)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/authorization/')
```

Any advice on how to match the id with the selected item would be appreciated. I'm sure my code is not very pythonic as I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outage = form.cleaned_data['outage'] # cleaned_data['outage'] is a model instance
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked, I also had to add '\`return u'%d' % self.outage_name_id` in my model.